# Google Visualization disable user selection

Tags: google-visualization

Is there anyway to disable user selection in google visualization chart (specifically org chart)

In the javascript, I have programmatically set selection on one of the node.  Is there anyway to disable user selection from that point on, so that the selection doesn't change even when user click on other section on the chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't disable but you can override

listen for the `'select'` event and `setSelection` to the desired `row`

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
    data.addRows([
      [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'},
       '', 'The President'],
      [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>'},
       'Mike', 'VP'],
      ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
      ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
      ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    // set selection on 'ready' and 'select'
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', setSelection);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', setSelection);

    function setSelection() {
      chart.setSelection([{row: 1}]);
    }

    chart.draw(data, {allowHtml: true});
  },
  packages:['orgchart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, another option might be to use the same css class for both `nodeClass` and `selectedNodeClass` in the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#configuration-options)

Comment: overriding the selection value works perfectly for my use case. Thanks

Comment: I found that leaving empty the `.setSelection()` call you can trick the plugin and disable selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable user selection by setting the **enableInteractivity** option on the chart.  From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart):

> Whether the chart throws user-based events or reacts to user
>   interaction. If false, the chart will not throw 'select' or other
>   interaction-based events (but will throw ready or error events), and
>   will not display hovertext or otherwise change depending on user
>   input.

Note that this will also remove the indication & tooltip that is displayed when the user hovers over chart elements which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: this is not true for the org chart, which doesn't have an option for `enableInteractivity`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @ziotino leaving empty .selection() will trick google charts to complete disable click/selection events on points.

```
// Listen to "select" event when we click on any of the "points" on the chart
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
        chart.setSelection();
    });
```